# Will we write all the code in views python file?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm just learning Django. My English is not good, I apologize in advance.

Can't I create separate files for each view, such as Codeigniter or Laravel? 
Do I have to write the codes of all pages in a single file? This is very difficult and complicated for me. There will be thousands of lines of code. Is there a good way?

Comment: No, you can make a separate file for each view. But it is not very "Pythonic" to do that in the first place. The same holdss for 1000 lines of code. Usually that amount means some modeling is not entirely correct.

Comment: for example: loginView.py blabla function and codes...... homeView.py blabla function and codes...can't?

Comment: you can perfectly do that. But it is more "Java" and "C#" to do so. Note that Python supports the OO paradigm, but it is not an OO programming language.

Comment: Thank you Willem, so Is there an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, I think you're using function-based views
but you should use class-based views
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

secondly, following this guide will help you splitting your view into multiple files
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/02/how-to-split-views-into-multiple-files.html